# Есть два вопроса на тему Data Science

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

я сейчас прохожу онлайн курс и там есть два вопроса на которые не могу правильно ответить.

Нужно провести анализ данных на основе датасета сайта IMBD https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nokVzSNxkUPil3aYRBI_fgzx25gtSEta
и ответить на два вопроса :

1.Какая студия сняла больше всего фильмов?
Варианты ответа:

- Universal Pictures (Universal)
- Paramount Pictures
- Columbia Pictures
- Warner Bros
- Twentieth Century Fox Film Corporation

Ответ "Universal Pictures (Universal)" не правильный. уже проверял

2.Какая студия сняла больше всего фильмов в 2015 году?

Варианты ответа:

- Universal Pictures
- Paramount Pictures
- Columbia Pictures
- Warner Bros- это ответ тоже не правильный.
- Twentieth Century Fox Film Corporation

Как будет выглядеть 2 кода на python которые дают ответы на данные вопросы?

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: А еще расскажите как вы проверяли правильность ответа, так как указанные ответы являются верными. По крайней мере у меня они совпали с вышеприведенными как в python, так и в Excell поиском.

Comment: спасибо за пояснение. ошибка была в том, что платформа глючила и не принимала мои ответы. Мой код вот такой был:1.temp_list = [i.split('|') for i in data['production_companies']]
def list_unrar(list_of_lists):
    result=[]
    for lst in list_of_lists:
      result.extend(lst)
    return result
temp_counter=Counter(list_unrar(temp_list))
temp_counter.most_common(1)

Comment: второй код production_companies_list = ['Universal Pictures', 'Paramount Pictures', 'Columbia Pictures', 'Warner Bros', 'Twentieth Century Fox Film Corporation']

production_companies = Counter()
for production_company in production_companies_list:
    production_companies[production_company] = len(data.loc[(data['release_year'] == 2015) & (data['production_companies'].str.contains(production_company))])
    
display(production_companies)

production_companies = pd.Series(production_companies, index=production_companies_list)
display(production_companies.idxmax())

Comment: в будущем учту,так как только начинаю в этом разбираться.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, задача не сильно тривиальная для новичка, поэтому дам набросок ответа по первому пункту.  Думаю, со вторым уже надо самому :-)  Как-то так, наверное:

```
import pandas as pd

# Вводим данные
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# Список киностудий
company = df['production_companies']

# Подсчитываем число вхождений каждой киностудии
counter = {}
for k in company: 
    counter[k] = counter.setdefault(k, 0) + 1

# Сортируем по количеству фильмов
sc = sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])

# Печатаем результат
for k,v in sc:
    print(k, v)
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала создаем новую таблицу `df2` по одной кинокомпании в столбце `company`.

Это нужно сделать потому, что в оригинальной таблице в столбце `production_companies` может быть несколько кинокомпаний перечисленных через символ `|`.

```
df1 = pd.concat(pd.DataFrame({
          "company": company,
          "year": row["release_year"],
          }, index=[ind])
              for ind, row in df.iterrows()
                  for company in row["production_companies"].split("|"))
```

Теперь уже можем решить ваше задания:

1. Группировка, затем подсчет и выбор (сколько хотим) наибольших:

   ```
   df1.groupby("company").company.count().nlargest(3)
   ```

   > ```
   > Universal Pictures    173
   > Warner Bros.          168
   > Paramount Pictures    122
   > ```
2. То же самое, только сначала выбор года 2015:

   ```
   df1[df1.year == 2015].groupby("company").company.count().nlargest(3)
   ```

   > ```
   > Warner Bros.                              12
   > Universal Pictures                        10
   > Twentieth Century Fox Film Corporation     8
   > ```

---

*Примечание:*

Мне кажется (на основании моих результатов), что вы в своем вопросе *заменили варианты ответов между заданиями:*

- к заданию 1 принадлежат варианты ответов из задания 2 и наоборот.

Comment: Кинокомпании перечислены через `|` в данных, а вы их в одну кучу пихаете. Над одним фильмом могли работать несколько кинокомпаний.

Comment: @Alex, спасибо вам, не заметил, исправил.

Comment: спасибо за ответ

Comment: @Kegon, не стоит, но см.[Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

1.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')    

# разделяем названия компаний
data['production_companies'].str.split('|', expand=True)

# соединим год выпуска со списком компаний
frame = pd.concat([data['release_year'],
                   data['production_companies'].str.split('|', expand=True)],
                   axis=1)

# сделаем единный столбец с названиями компаний
frame = frame.melt(id_vars=['release_year'])

# посмотрим на компании, которые встречаются чаще всего
frame['value'].value_counts()
```

2.

```
# выбрать только те значения, которые удовлетворяют условию
flt = data['release_year'] == 2015

# проделать то же самое, что и в первом вопросе но уже на:
data.loc[flt, :]
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ